# How do I get a Helper-Tool to access a File on macOS?

Tags: macos, sandbox

My App has a CLI Helper-Tool.
I have created an Entitlements-File with

```
<key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key> <true/>
<key>com.apple.security.inherit</key> <true/>
```

The Helper-Tool is signed. It is started and gets its Arguments by NSTask. But it cannot access a File which I drag & drop to the Main-App. What could be the Problem?